# How to change text size of SPINNER (Android)

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to decrease the font size of the spinner, and I created an XML file called spinner_item.

spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#800080" />
```

method to load the spinner:

```
private void loadCustomServiceSpinner(String workRequestType) {

    CustomServiceDBQueries csQueries = new CustomServiceDBQueries();
    customServices = csQueries.selectCustomService(workRequestType);

    String[] strCustomService = new String[customServices.size() + 1];
    strCustomService[0] = "";

    int i = 1;
    for (CustomService cs : customServices) {
        strCustomService[i] = cs.getCustomServiceName();
        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, strCustomService);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_drop_default);

    Spinner SpnCustomService = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpnCustomService);
    SpnCustomService.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I do not see any changes, the source may be 20 or 50 SP SP that does not change anything. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should make `Custom Array Adapter` for this.

Comment: Or create a Style in xml and set that on any textview you want to create a uniform look throughout the application.